# Derived method invoked before derived class is fully constructed?

Tags: python

The following code prints `30` after the call to the `multiply` method invokes the derived `multiply` method:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.multiply(15)
        print(self.i)

    def multiply(self, i):
        self.i = 4 * i


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def multiply(self, i):
        self.i = 2 * i


    obj = B()
```

First `super().__init__()` is invoked and then, because `multiply` overrides, the derived `multiply` method is invoked.

How is it possible if the object is not even fully constructed (if we're inside the base class's `__init__` method then we haven't even finished constructing the base object, so how come we can invoke the derived method )?

Comment: The object *is* fully constructed - `__init__` is initialisation, not creation. What did you *expect* to happen here?

Comment: Doesn't full construction require that the interpreter go over the entire class hierarchy before being able to call overridden methods ?

Comment: That is part of creating the *classes*, not the *instances* - and that *has* already finished, which is why you can instantiate `B` to begin with.

Comment: Then what does the object construction include ? What kind of data is created when the object is constructed (besides variables)?

Comment: Did you mean to have `obj = B()` *outside* the definition of `B`?

Comment: You never "construct a base object", rather, the base classes' method is called on the derived class instance. And `__init__` isn't the constructor, but even if it were, it would still work. Methods belong to the *class* not the instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__init__` is called *after* `__new__` returns; that is, `obj = B()` is approximately equivalent to

```
obj = B.__new__(B)  # create the new object
obj.__init__()      # initialize it
```

Typically, a class does not override `__new__`; it just defers to `object.__new__` instead. (Even when it does define `__new__`, it has to ensure that `object.__new__` ultimately gets called.)

Comment: This is true but rather orthogonal to the issue. Even if init was the constructor, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading the question, this is *exactly* the issue. The object *is* fully constructed by the time `__init__` is called.

Comment: Yes, but that is irrelevant. The methods exist on the *class* so even if the object were not full constructed you could still use a method on them.

Comment: It sounds like the OP thinks that `B.multiply` is called from `A.__init__` after some `A`-portion of the instance is created but before "all" of the instance of `B` is created (as if the calls to `A.__init__` and `B.__init__` are somehow interleaved with the object creation process).

Comment: Yeah, that's another misunderstanding. There are a lot to choose from. And of course, an `A` instance is never created. Rather, various attribute references are resolved on the class mro as appropriate. I think your answer resolves some confusion, but fundamentally, the issue is that these methods already exist even when no instances exist

Comment: Thanks ! that's exactly the understanding i lacked.  __new__() is what ensures the object is fully created before i use __init__()